# Select by bit/boolean value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to get all administrators in a certain system. I have a `bit` column called `isAdmin` and a column called `UserID` which is a primary key.

I tried to select by the bit the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM UsersTable WHERE UserID = 2 AND isAdmin = 1
```

But although the user with `UserID` equals to `2` is not an admin, it still fills the `DataSet` with it. I'm having a hard time with it, I've also tried comparing `isAdmin` to `'True'` with no success.

How do I accomplish that? How do I filter by boolean (bit) value?

EDIT:

After another review over my code I saw a couple of interesting things. When I had a new `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` and while doing the same query as mentioned in the above, it worked perfectly - it didn't return a thing (as it should, becuase user num. 2 isn't an administrator) and when I mentioned `isAdmin = 0`, it did return it, as should.

But, for some weird reason - in the other file (the one of the actual application), the exact same string is performed and yet the result is totally different. I actually get 2 rows back from the database. And the even crazier part is that them BOTH contain the same user (the single administrator currently in the database), so I actually somehow get a duplicate row...?

Here's my piece of code and a couple of outputs I tested mentioned in it:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(/*My Connection String, identical in all files*/);
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UsersTable WHERE UserID = " + Session["UserID"] + " AND isAdmin = 1"; //I put the output in an alert message box - OUTPUT: SELECT * FROM UsersTable WHERE UserID = 2 AND isAdmin = 1 (as expected). Note that this whole chunk is in a 'if(Session["UserID"] != null)'.
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(u);
        conn.Close();

        if (u.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) //u.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 2, how is that?
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + u.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"] + ", " + u.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Username"] + "');</script>"); //This, for instance, outputs - 'admin', 'admin' (note there's only one user with the username - 'admin' and he is an administrator.
            /* Here I'm doing some things exclusively for the admin */
        }
```

This is my chunk of code, my application is not multi-threaded, nor anyone is accessing `u` while I access it. The problem really freaks me out because I can see no reason for it to happen.

Note: When I actually change `cmd.CommandText` to `SELECT * FROM UsersTable WHERE isAdmin = 1` I get 3 rows (there's an overall of 3 rows in the table), ALL of these rows are filled with duplicates of the `admin` row. What could happen here?

EDIT2: Solved. The `DataSet` was, in fact, filled already with 2 rows, as it was global. I thought that `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` was emptying then filling, I guess I was wrong. Thanks a bunch to everyone.

Comment: Verify that your column definitions and values are what you expect them to be. select isAdmin from UsersTable where UserID = 2;            If it really is a boolean then 0 should be false and 1 should be true.

Comment: What you have should do it... so when you do that select statement... does it show the isAdmin value = 0?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Indeed, that was the problem, I just figured it out as the one I was using was global... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sharing the `DataSet` around then you need to make sure you [`Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) the table if you want it to potentially be empty.

Note the description of [`SqlDataAdapter.Fill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Adds or refreshes rows in the DataSet.

It says nothing about *removing* existing rows.

---

Also, please use [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by Parameters? The link didn't say much.

Comment: @Zim - instead of having `WHERE UserID = " + Session["UserID"] + "` you would have `WHERE UserID = @UserID`. You would then add the required data as a parameter of the `SqlCommand` object. This keeps the *code* (SQL) separate from the *data* and is a very good habit to get into  - especially if some of your database work accepts input from the users. Parameterization is the key technique to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which is one of the biggest classes of security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32721/2

isAdmin should be returning false, not 0, if it is boolean.

Edit: another version.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/067f0e/1

Comment: I believe that is MySQL syntax, not SQL Server.

Comment: @BrianPressler you are correct, an oversight on my part. I changed the version to MS SQL SERVER 2014 and the results are telling me the same thing. Edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: What i mean is "Where isAdmin = false" is not valid SQL Server Syntax.  The word "False" is not a SQL Server key word and you will get a syntax error if you try to use it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your posted query but with what you said in your post; I doubt you have used a `OR` condition instead of `AND` like

```
SELECT * FROM UsersTable WHERE UserID = 2 OR isAdmin = 1
```

You can try changing your query like below which will fetch only users who are also admins.

```
SELECT * FROM UsersTable WHERE isAdmin = 1
```